# Views exposed filter to take multiple values

Tags: 7, views

I'm running a D7 system and have a requirement where I want user to be able to pass multiple values in one of the exposed filters.

I've got hundreds of nodes called 'group' and I want user to be able to pass multiple 'group' names in order to filter results.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module for this type of requirement you have.

Using this module you can add multi-select option for group names, so you will filter your results on multiple values.

Comment: I can't use multi-select in BEF as I have hundreds of nodes. What I really want is to be able to search the names e.g 'yellow group, white group' etc.